# MySQL - JOIN 2 tables with 2 id's in common as query

Tags: mysql, sql

i have this problem:

my sql database looks like this:

```
table "uitslagen" :

id
teamid1
teamid2
uitslag

table "teams" :

id
name
```

i want to join the teamid1 and teamid2 with the teams.id so i get the name back for each team on the competition.

what i want to get is this:

```
uitslagen.id | teamid1 AS teams.name | teamid2 AS teams.name | uitslagen.uitslag
```

example:

```
1 | jong ajax | ado den haag | 2:1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT
  U.id,
  T1.name as Team1_Name,
  T2.name as Team2_Name,
  U.uitslag
FROM uitslagen U
  JOIN teams T1
    ON U.teamid1 = T1.id
  JOIN teams T2
    ON U.teamid2 = T2.id
```

Comment: i get this error:
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'T2.naam as Team2_Naam U.uitslag FROM uitslagen U JOIN teams T1 ON U.team' at line 4

Comment: I have omitted semicolons between result columns.

Answer (score 0):

Join the `teams` table twice and use different alias names to differ between them

```
select u.id, 
       teamid1 AS t1.name,
       teamid2 AS t2.name,
       u.uitslag
from uitslagen as u
join teams as t1 on t1.id = u.teamid1
join teams as t2 on t2.id = u.teamid2
```